# CSS scroll IE10 and Chrome

Tags: css

I have one small code, but it works so different between chrome ( look nice ) and IE.
On chrome the scroll just are show enough to see all divs. On IE the scroll have the size of css container-inner.

Is a little stupid, but in this case IE10 are work better but I like the Chrome style.

http://jsfiddle.net/VpZ8C/

someone know how I can fix it?

```
<div class='container-outer' style="-ms-overflow-style:auto;">
    <div class='container-inner'>
        <div class="box">1</div><div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
    </div>
</div> 
<style> 
.container-outer  { 
    overflow-x: auto;  
    width: 855px; 
    height: 250px; 
    -ms-overflow-style: auto; 
     border: 1px solid black; } 
.box {
   width: 250px !important;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   height: 150px;
   float: left; 
} 
.container-inner { width: 2500px; } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use relative placing of containers using percentage instead of fixed borders or use box sizing(http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)
Example 1:

```
    #container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    } 

    #header {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    }
```

Example 2:(Using Box Sizing)

```
    #container { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    /* Since this element now uses border-box sizing, the 10px of horizontal
    padding will be drawn inside the 80% width */
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }
```